# How to setup TestNG in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I am using selenium webdriver for website testing. Now I want to setup TestNG in my selenium webdriver. How it possible? Is there any JAR files for testng?

Answer (score 2):

Add testng maven dependency to your pom.xml file. Jars will be auto downloaded. Then you can start using testng in your project.

Answer (score 1):

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng
YOu can see all versions her, download the JAR files or use the dependencies in your POM.xml if you use Maven

Answer (score 0):

You can get the testng from the eclipse market place by searching Testng,simple install that you can now use testng on your project.

You can also find this jar for testng libraries and add it to your project.

http://testng.org/testng-6.8.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can install testng from Market place if not found install as software. Details are provided in documentation

https://testng.org/doc/download.html

Once installation is done and eclipse restarted then add TestNG library to you project and then good to go.

For build tools you need testng jars, you can download from maven repository. If you are using maven add dependency in pom.xml as said in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install TestNG from - TestNG P2 - https://testng.org/testng-p2-update-site. Steps are mentioned below:-

1. Launch Eclipse and go to Help option present at the top and select -"Install New Software".
2. A new dialog box will appear. Mention Name as TestNG and location as "http://beust.com/eclipse/" and click on Add button.
3. This time we will see TestNG added in Install dialog box.
4. Once the installation is completed, you will get a message to Restart the Eclipse and select to Restart the Eclipse.

You are all set. In case you want to know more about TestNG, you can refer this [link](https://qaautomation.expert/2019/10/30/testng-framework-how-to-download-and-install-testng-in-eclipse/).

Comment: it's preferred to put all the relevant information into the post itself rather than provide links, in case those links die in the future.